# The CKEditor config "micro" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor

[image]

when i was running my project i got this error,
i tried these solutions but it didn't work well,

> ```
> php bin/console ckeditor:install
> ```

also i tried yarn:

> ```
> $ npm install --save ckeditor4@^4.13.0
>  AND
> $ yarn add ckeditor4@^4.13.0
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

micro is a ckeditor toolbar configuration, defines what buttons will be available (like bold, italic etc), update your

> config/packages/fos_ckeditor.yaml

:

```
    twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'

fos_ck_editor:
    default_config: standard
    configs:
        standard:
            toolbar: standard
        full:
            toolbar: full
        micro:
            toolbar:
                - [Bold, Italic, Underline, Link, Unlink, Source]
            bodyClass: 'columns'
            contentsCss: null
            enterMode: 2 #CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
            shiftEnterMode: 2
            coreStyles_bold: { element: 'b', overrides: 'strong' }
            height: 90px
            removePlugins: elementspath
            resize_enabled: false
```